# How does the polymer.json file get utilized in a Polymer app?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-cli

After using the Polymer CLI, there is a generated polymer.json file. I'm having a hard time Googling/finding information on what this file is used for and how. Can someone explain how this file affects my application?

Answer (score 0):

I found all the answers in the docs eventually.
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli

Answer (score 0):

`polymer.json` is a config file that lets you specify your build entrypoint, shell, and fragments, rather than having to pass these in as command-line flags to `polymer build`.

The [Build configuration file](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli#build-config) section from the Polymer CLI guide talks specifically about `polymer.json`. The [Serve your app](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/server) doc from the App Toolbox docs also has some good information for understanding how Polymer CLI builds projects.